# Which is better for creating tables of group theory info, GAP or MAGMA?

Tags: gr.group-theory, mathematical-software

Specifically, I want to compute the set of values of $|G:\text{ker}(\chi)|/\chi(1)$ for all the characters of a p-group, for a lot of p-groups. I don't know how to use either program, so before I invest in learning it, I'm wondering about the pros and cons of GAP and MAGMA (when compared to each other).

Comment: Gap is free, Magma is not, that may make a difference.

Comment: I have access to magma through my school.

Comment: Magma is also not open-source, so a proof that depends on a Magma computation can't be made fully public.

Comment: I am afraid that this question is in danger of being  or becoming opinion based.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The corresponding Magma function (using the same name as Stefan) is

```
CharacterKernelIndicesDividedByValueAtOne := function ( G )
  return [Index(G,Kernel(c))/Degree(c) : c in CharacterTable(G) ];
end function;
```

Both the GAP and Magma versions returned the answer almost instantly on SmallGroup(3^6,300). The Magma version was slightly faster on a group of order $2^{15}$.

Answer (score 6):

To answer your specific question, in [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org) you can compute the
desired values for a given group $G$ with the following function:

```
CharacterKernelIndicesDividedByValueAtOne := function ( G )

  return List(Irr(G),chi->Index(G,KernelOfCharacter(chi))/
                          ValuesOfClassFunction(chi)[1]);
end;
```

You can do for example

```
gap> List(AllGroups(16),CharacterKernelIndicesDividedByValueAtOne);
[ [ 1, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16 ], 
  [ 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4 ], 
  [ 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4 ], [ 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4 ], 
  [ 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8 ], 
  [ 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8 ], [ 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 8, 8 ], 
  [ 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 8, 8 ], [ 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 8, 8 ], 
  [ 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4 ], 
  [ 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4 ], [ 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4 ], 
  [ 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 8 ], 
  [ 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 ] ]
```

to apply this function to all groups of order $16$, or

```
gap> List(Filtered(AllGroups(64), G -> NilpotencyClassOfGroup(G) = 5),
>         CharacterKernelIndicesDividedByValueAtOne);
[ [ 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 8, 8, 16, 16, 16, 16, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32 ], 
  [ 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 8, 8, 16, 16, 16, 16, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32 ], 
  [ 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 8, 8, 16, 16, 16, 16, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32 ] ]
```

to apply it to all groups of order $64$ whose nilpotence class is $5$.

Comment: I'll need some p-groups to do this with, does GAP have a collection of p-groups I can call? Does it have a function to evaluate the nilpotence class of a group? I forgot I'll need that information as well.

Comment: @ArcanaNoir: Yes, it has -- see [here](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/sgl.html) (Magma has just the same database). The function to compute the nilpotence class of a group is `NilpotencyClassOfGroup`.

Comment: To be precise, GAP Small Groups Library contains more groups than MAGMA: see http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/sgl.html. Also, some more $p$-groups appeared in the recently developed SglPPow package, see http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/sglppow.html